# angular dependency injection not resolving for library component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, library-project

it is a simple situation.  In my library project called lib-a, defines 3 classes: libAModule, LibAComponent and MyService.
LibAComponent has a constructor that takes MyService as a parameter.
MyService is decorated with

```
@Injector()
```

attribute.

In the Root Application's appModule, i provide that service:

```
providers: [MyService]
```

the appModule also has a constructor that takes MyService as a parameter.

When i run the app the dependency is resolved in the appModule's constructor (verified by stepping through in the debugger), however, when trying to render the LibAComponent i get the following error in the browsers console window:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[libAComponent-> MyService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[libAComponent-> MyService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MyService!
```

I can fix that by updating the

```
@Injector({provideIn: 'root'})
```

attribute on the MyService.  However, theoretically it is equivalent to providing the service in the appModule as i am doing.  The reason i want to do it this way is because ultimately, i want to provide the service in appModule as such:

```
providers: [{provide: MyService, useClass: MyExtendedService }]
```

where myExtendedService is defined outside of the library project.

Can anyone figure out why i get that error when i provide the service through appModule?

Comment: What Angular version are you using? Can give us app.module and MyService.ts ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
 providers: [ MyService ]
```

in stead of

```
provider: [{provide: MyService, useClass: MyExtendedService }]
```

Comment: I am sorry, but that isn't it. In the question, it was typo on my part I am using providers and not provider.